# Changed a method variable from datetime to string and getting error on copying when trying to build

Tags: c#, asp.net, build

I had to fix a method in my class and when I go to run the webform, I get this error and I really don't what is causing the issue, I know what it means I just don't know how to fix it or why it keeps throwing the error and the error is.

> Error 3 Unable to copy "obj\Debug\CsharpBasicTravelApp.dll"to "bin\CsharpBasicTravelApp.dll". Access to the path 'bin\CsharpBasicTravelApp.dll' is denied.

All I did was change a variable in a method from `datetime` to `string`.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding, save changes and restart IDE?

Comment: That is what was needed, was a restart. It never even dawned on me that a simple restart of the ide would fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the assembly is still being used by another process. Make sure you closed all development Webservers etc.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for the explanation, I did a restart of the ide, which was suggested, and it works. Now that you explained it that if I ever run into this issue again i'll know why.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your build.  After the compile finishes it can't copy the library to the final directory (`bin`).  You have to change the rights to that directory to allow you use them... they are probably set to read only.  Make a backup first.

Comment: Hogan thanks for the reply, I got it resolved, it was a case of restarting the ide.